# dictionary python with a csv file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I'm new at all this coding but have lots of motivation even when things don't work.

I'm trying to work on a dictionary with a CSV file. I get to open and edit a new file but I think I'm missing something when trying to read from the csv file.
I'm getting errors in rows 39-41 i'm probably doing something wrong but what is it?
Here is the code:

```
import csv
import os
import os.path

phonebook = {}
def print_menu():
    print('1. Print phone book')
    print('2. add phone book')
    print('3. look for number using first name only')
    print('4. look by last name')
    print('5. exit')
    print()

menu_selection = 0

while menu_selection != 5:

    if os.path.isfile('my_phonebook.csv') == True:  
        csv_file = open('my_phonebook.csv', 'a', newline = '')
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    else:
        csv_file = open('my_phonebook.csv', 'w', newline = '')
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        headers = ['first_name','last_name','phone_number']
        writer.writerow(headers)
    print_menu()
    menu_selection = int(input('type menu selection number'))

    if menu_selection == 2:  #add list in phone book
        first_name = input("enter first name: ")
        last_name = input("enter last name: ")
        phone_number = input("enter phone number: ")
        writer.writerow([first_name,last_name,phone_number])
        csv_file.close()
    elif menu_selection == 1: #print phone book
        print("phone book:")
        listGen = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|') #error starts here and in the next two rows...
        for row in csv_file:
            print(row)
    elif menu_selection == 3: #look for number using first name only
        print('look up number')
        first_name = input('first name:')
        if first_name in phonebook:
            print('the number is', phonebook[phone_number])
        else:
            print('name not found')
    elif menu_selection == 4: #print all details of last name entered
        print('search by last name')
        last_name = input('please enter last name: ')
        for row in csv_file:
            print(row)
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the errors you obtain?
In python, those messages contains a lot of information, and with a bit of train, you will be able to correct easily a major part of the errors just by reading them.

Comment: What about following the python's doc examples : https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples ?

Answer (score 1):

Does the file have any contents? Looks like you're trying to loop over an empty iterator of lines. Try something like...

```
for row in csv_file:
    print(row)
else:
    print('no phone numbers')
```

And see what you get.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer..
i get error when adding your code

 for row in csv_file:
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code. 
There were some other errors also which I tried to fix.Did couple of changes for the same.

For reading csv, I didn't use csv reader module.

If you want to use that, please replace the code in search() function.

```
import csv
import os
import os.path

phonebook = {}
def print_menu():
    print('1. Print phone book')
    print('2. add phone book')
    print('3. look for number using first name only')
    print('4. look by last name')
    print('5. exit')
    print()

def search(name):
    phonebook = open('my_phonebook.csv','r')
    name_found = True
    for line in phonebook:
        if name in line:
            fname,lname,num = line.split(',')
            print "First Name is ",fname.strip()
            print "Last Name is ",lname.strip()
            print 'the number is', num.strip()

            name_found = True
    if  not name_found:
        print('name not found')
    return    
menu_selection = 0

while menu_selection != 5:


    print_menu()
    menu_selection = int(input('type menu selection number - '))

    if menu_selection == 2:  #add list in phone book
        if os.path.isfile('my_phonebook.csv') == True:  
            csv_file = open('my_phonebook.csv', 'a')
            writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        else:
            csv_file = open('my_phonebook.csv', 'w')
            writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
            headers = ['first_name','last_name','phone_number']
            writer.writerow(headers)
        first_name = input("enter first name: ")
        last_name = input("enter last name: ")
        phone_number = input("enter phone number: ")
        writer.writerow([first_name,last_name,phone_number])
        csv_file.close()

    elif menu_selection == 1: #print phone book
        print("phone book:")
        if os.path.isfile('my_phonebook.csv') == True:  
            csv_file=open('my_phonebook.csv','r')

            for row in csv_file:
                print(row)
            csv_file.close()
        else:
            print "Phone book file not created. First create it to read it"

    elif menu_selection == 3: #look for number using first name only
        print('look up number')
        first_name = input('first name:')
        search(first_name)


    elif menu_selection == 4: #print all details of last name entered
        print('search by last name')
        last_name = input('please enter last name: ')
        search(last_name)
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>python b.py
1. Print phone book
2. add phone book
3. look for number using first name only
4. look by last name
5. exit
()
type menu selection number - 1
phone book:
Phone book file not created. First create it to read it
1. Print phone book
2. add phone book
3. look for number using first name only
4. look by last name
5. exit
()
type menu selection number - 2
enter first name: "Dinesh"
enter last name: "Pundkar"
enter phone number: "12345"
1. Print phone book
2. add phone book
3. look for number using first name only
4. look by last name
5. exit
()
type menu selection number - 1
phone book:
first_name,last_name,phone_number

Dinesh,Pundkar,12345

1. Print phone book
2. add phone book
3. look for number using first name only
4. look by last name
5. exit
()
type menu selection number - 3
look up number
first name:"Dinesh"
First Name is  Dinesh
Last Name is  Pundkar
the number is 12345
1. Print phone book
2. add phone book
3. look for number using first name only
4. look by last name
5. exit
()
type menu selection number - 4
search by last name
please enter last name: "Pundkar"
First Name is  Dinesh
Last Name is  Pundkar
the number is 12345
1. Print phone book
2. add phone book
3. look for number using first name only
4. look by last name
5. exit
()
type menu selection number - 5

C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>
```